# How can I analyze Django ORM query performance on a server with DRF Endpoints only?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, query-analyzer

Previous Django apps I've worked on have used HTML template rendering, and `django-debug-toolbar` has proven to be a valuable way to analyze ORM SQL queries and find places to optimize.

The current app I'm working on uses Django for `django-rest-framework` REST endpoints only, and has no HTML views.

Is there a way I can analyze queries in a similar way?  I looked into `django-debug-toolbar` + `django-debug-panel` (with a Chrome extension), but it's quite a bit out of date, requiring Django 2.1 or earlier.

Comment: `django-debug-toolbar` alone is enough to analyse your queries performance.

Comment: Use `rest-framework` defualt browsable page, with django-debug-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about django-debug-toolbar for API testing, because request are made with AJAx in swagger UI and other browsable tool API.

But you can look Django-silk with is more usable for your case with same information of Django-Debug-Toolbar: https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk

Hope this can help

Answer (score 1):

You can try [dj-tracker](https://github.com/Tijani-Dia/dj-tracker). It will keep track of **all** your queries (and can even give hints to optimize them).